# Nextjs state object update from child in loop not consistent

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is a simple example:

```
const [objs,setObjs] = useState([...MyArrayOfObjects]);
const [cachedObjs,setCachedObjs] = useState({});
const update_cache = function(key,obj){
    let co = Object.assign({},cachedObjs);
    co[key] = obj;
    setCachedObjs(co);
}

return(
    objs.map((o,idx)=>{
        <thing cache_function={update_cache} key={etc...}/>
    })
)
```

My rendered "things" do some calculations etc and what I would like to do is use the function `update_cache` to store those calculations... however it seems as though I only end up with the `key => obj` value of the last looped object in my array... e.g; If I print my `cachedObjs` in the console I only get the key of the last object in the array
(with its calculated value).

Inside the "thing" component:

```
const update_parent = function(){
    properties.update_cache('myUniqueKey',{foo:'bar'})
}

useEffect(()=>{
   if(calculations_done){
        update_parent()
   }
},[]);
```

I'm assuming the "things" are referencing the `cachedObjs` at its initial state and overwriting at each iteration... is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Where and how do you call `update_cache`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated the question with an example.

Comment: Use the callback version of the state setter to account for the possibly just-changed value

Comment: @CertainPerformance inside the child component? setCachedObjs?